# Best framework if moving from Python/AppEngine to PHP

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, frameworks

I'm been programming with Python in AppEngine for the last months, and I need to use PHP for a new project.

What PHP framework could you recommend me that feels like working with AppEngine?

Some things I'd want to keep are:

- Easy database definition (models.py) and abstraction
- Easy URI definitions
- Easy deploy

One thing I definitively want to benefit from using PHP is speed.

Since I'm a junior developer, I'd also like to find a framework with a strong community and/or documentation available.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Moving to PHP is a wrong choice.

Comment: I need to use PHP for this project :( I wish I could do it in AppEngine

Comment: What framework are you using now?

Comment: If you are using a framework in Python, you may find a framework in PHP that uses similar conventions.

Comment: Some parts of Django (for templates and localization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [symfony](http://symfony.com/) webframework. It uses the [twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) templating engine which is similar to the one Django uses. Furthermore it is fairly inspired by Django in the way it is build, and there is an easy way of doing datamapping.